# Determine if a file is in the process of being deleted on Windows in C

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have a file that was opened with with the Windows API CreateFile() using the FILE_SHARE_DELETE flag so that I can delete it while the file handle is still open.  But in the window between the first process deleting the file and the process ending, I want to be able to tell that the file is being deleted so that I can go into a retry loop.

I found error code 303 that looks exactly like what I'm looking for:

```
ERROR_DELETE_PENDING
    303 (0x12F)
    The file cannot be opened because it is in the process of being deleted.
```

But I can't find what I can use that will return this code for me.  Does anyone know how I can determine that my file is in this state of being deleted but still has an open handle?

Comment: You are correct.  That question covers my issue exactly.  What do I do with my question then?

Answer (score 4):

On Vista and later, you can open the file with `CreateFile()` (make sure the `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` flag is specified so the open can succeed) and then use [`GetFileInformationByHandleEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364953.aspx) to retrieve the file's [`FILE_STANDARD_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364401.aspx) structure.  It has a `BOOLEAN DeletePending` data member that will be `TRUE` if the file has been marked for deletion.

Comment: On pre-Vista you can use [`NtQueryInformationFile`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/File/NtQueryInformationFile.html) (`GetFileInformationByHandleEx` is basically a wrapper around it).

Comment: After the first process deletes the file, the second process can no longer open a file handle on it.  `CreateFile()` fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Answer (score 1):

To get that error code you need to call `GetLastError` immediately after the `CreateFile` function fails.  It will return `ERROR_DELETE_PENDING` (the constant for error code `303`) when that situation occurs

Comment: `CreateFile()` returns `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, not `ERROR_DELETE_PENDING`.